# Create sequences with specified lengths

Tags: r, vector, sequence

Is there a way to create sequences from 1 to each value of the vector `a`?

```
a <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3)
b <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3)
```

The values in `a` can be higher than 3.

Comment: What's the logic between a and b?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sequence` to get sequences with length described in `a`. `sequence` starts by default at 1 with an increment of 1.

```r
sequence(a)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 2 1 1 1 2 3

all.equal(sequence(a), b)
# [1] TRUE
```